# How can nettle 2.7.1 be upgraded on Centos 7 to nettle 3.7.2?

Tags: centos7

Qualys vulnerability scan recently identified a Nettle Cryptographics Library Vulnerability:

*The vulnerability in ECDSA signature verification that could lead to a denial of service attack*

The recommendation is to upgrade to version 3.7.2. However the latest rpm for Centos 7 that I can find is the 2.7.1 version that is already installed. Should I be able to remove the currently installed nettle using yum and reinstall from scratch using nettle-3.7.3.tar.gz?